# To remove vowels from string-The answer that i get after this is the same as input. Can you please tell me why?

Tags: java

Can you please check the error in the code. The answer that i get after this is the same as input. Can you please tell me why?

```
package practiceTest1;    
public class RemoveVowel {
    public String WithoutVowels(String str) {
    String withoutVowel = "";
        String vowels = "aeiou";
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < vowels.length(); k++) {
                if (str.charAt(j) != vowels.charAt(k)) {    
                    continue;
                }                   
            }
            withoutVowel = withoutVowel + str.charAt(j);
        }
        return withoutVowel;
}    
public static void main(String[] str)
  {
      RemoveVowel rv=new RemoveVowel();
      String wV= rv.WithoutVowels("String");
      System.out.println(wV);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop does nothing.

Comment: Try to use regex : `str.replaceAll( "[aeiouAEIOU]", "" )`, you will get expected output

Comment: yes regex is the best option (y)

Answer (score 0):

Your getting this because you are always copying str char to the `withoutVowel` , whether it is a vowel or not your function will copy it. What you can do is keep a boolean check which tells you whether the current char isVowel or not, if it is not than only copy that char.

```
for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
        boolean isVowel = false;
        for (int k = 0; k < vowels.length(); k++) {
              if (str.charAt(j) != vowels.charAt(k)) {    
                    continue;
               } 
              isVowel = true;                   
       }
        if(!isVowel)    
          withoutVowel = withoutVowel + str.charAt(j);
}
```

Plus try using `StringBuilder` instead of String for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (str.charAt(j) != vowels.charAt(k)) {    
                        continue;
                    }
```

I guess you would have written above line of code for "dont do anything if jth character of str is not matching with kth character of "aeiou" " but where is the condition for "if jth char of str matches with  kth char of aeiou. Instead of writing condition for not matching you should write condition for matching because only if jth char is vowel then u need to do something.
Take a look at below code

```
 public String WithoutVowels(String str) {
        String withoutVowel = "";
            String vowels = "aeiou";
            for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
                String temp=""+str.charAt(j);
                for (int k = 0; k < vowels.length(); k++) {
                    if (str.charAt(j) == vowels.charAt(k)) {    
                        temp="";
                    }   
                }
                withoutVowel = withoutVowel + temp; ;
            }
            return withoutVowel;
    }
```